# how to create admin account as a duplicate root account for telnet and disable root login over network?

Tags: sudo, root, telnet

I've been searching for the answer to this but all I find is "It doesn't work".

I am a new, yes. I am still a student and i still learn about it. I am happy to break my OS and format it many times if it comes to that but restrictions of ANY kind on my OS enrage me. I want to be able to break stuff if I want, then learn how I broke it and how to fix it.

I want the safety locks off.

Please tell me how to create admin account as a duplicate root account for telnet and disable root login over network.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Well, the safety locks are there for a purpose, and you may learn more by studying why the locks are there in the first place. Having said that:

1. Give user administration permissions:

   **Inexperienced users: don't do this. You will break your system.**

   `sudo usermod -u 0 [username]`
2. Disable telnet login for a particular user, without disabling local login: Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and enter `sudo nano /etc/hosts.deny`. Enter your password when asked, and press enter. At the end of the file, add the line `in.telnetd username@hostIP`, replacing hostIP with the IP address of the computer that you don't want user `username` to login from.

Comment: "Inexperienced users: don't do this. You will break your system." Not if you create a new user first ;)

Comment: what is the change in the /etc/hosts.deny ??
can you tell me the steps for make it. please..

Comment: @gabrielwambrauw I edited the question.

Comment: and how about the server is linux and the client is windows..?
how to solved this case?

Comment: The changes I describe are made on the server. The client just follows the protocol, its OS is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks you... Do you have another way??? please.

Comment: Another way to do what? And what is wrong with my way? I don't follow you.

Comment: not wrong.. i just want to know another way to make user like root to login in telnet..